# Can't use coroutines in Java... but what about insert Kotlin coroutines?

Tags: java, kotlin

```
Linux Mint 20
Java 11
```

In Java project I need lightweight threads. The coroutines is good candidates for this.
But in Java not exist coroutines.
But what about use Kotlin corouines in Java project?

Smt like this:

In build.gradle:

```
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib"
implementation 'org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-coroutines-core-jvm:1.5.2'
```

Then create Kotlin class that use Kotlin coroutines:

```
import kotlinx.coroutines.delay
import kotlinx.coroutines.launch
import kotlinx.coroutines.runBlocking

class CoroutineKotlin {

    fun runCoroutine() = runBlocking { // this: CoroutineScope
        launch { // launch a new coroutine and continue
            delay(3000L) // non-blocking delay for 3 seconds (default time unit is ms)
            println("Kotlin: From Kotlin coroutines!") // print after delay
        }
        println("Kotlin: Hello") // main coroutine continues while a previous one is delayed
    }

    fun runCoroutinesWithSuspend() = runBlocking { // this: CoroutineScope
        launch { doWorld() }
        println("Hello")
    }

    suspend fun doWorld() {
        delay(1000L)
        println("From Kotlin coroutines (suspend)!")
    }

    //Coroutines ARE light-weigh
    fun runManyCoroutines() = runBlocking {
        repeat(10_000) { // launch a lot of coroutines
            launch {
                delay(5000L)
                print(".")
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Then is Java class call Kotlin methods:

```
   import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;
import java.time.LocalDateTime;

public class App {
    private static Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(App.class);

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        System.out.println("Java: Call Kotlin code from Java code, currentDate = " + LocalDateTime.now());
        CoroutineKotlin coroutineKotlin = new CoroutineKotlin();

        System.out.println("Java: Before call runCoroutine, currentDate = " + LocalDateTime.now());
        coroutineKotlin.runCoroutine();
        // call only after finish "runCoroutine()"
        System.out.println("Java: After call runCoroutine, currentDate = " + LocalDateTime.now());

        System.out.println("\nJava: Before call runCoroutinesWithSuspend, currentDate = " + LocalDateTime.now());
        coroutineKotlin.runCoroutinesWithSuspend();
        // call only after finish "runCoroutinesWithSuspend()"
        System.out.println("Java: After call runCoroutinesWithSuspend, currentDate = " + LocalDateTime.now());

        System.out.println("\nJava: Before call runManyCoroutines, currentDate = " + LocalDateTime.now());
        coroutineKotlin.runManyCoroutines();
        // call only after finish "runManyCoroutines()"
        System.out.println("\nJava: After call runManyCoroutines, currentDate = " + LocalDateTime.now());

    }
}
```

And here result:

```
    Java: Call Kotlin code from Java code, currentDate = 2021-10-15T15:44:58.391
Java: Before call runCoroutine, currentDate = 2021-10-15T15:44:58.392
Kotlin: Hello
Kotlin: From Kotlin coroutines!
Java: After call runCoroutine, currentDate = 2021-10-15T15:45:01.424

Java: Before call runCoroutinesWithSuspend, currentDate = 2021-10-15T15:45:01.425
Hello
From Kotlin coroutines (suspend)!
Java: After call runCoroutinesWithSuspend, currentDate = 2021-10-15T15:45:02.428

Java: Before call runManyCoroutines, currentDate = 2021-10-15T15:45:02.428
.............. 10000 dots here
Java: After call runManyCoroutines, currentDate = 2021-10-15T15:45:07.538
```

As you can see two Kotlin's methods are not suspend and another method is **suspend**. And this 3 methods success call from Java code.

Moreover the third Kotlin method `runManyCoroutines` create **10000 coroutines**. And also no problems with use this from Java code!

Is it good solution?

Comment: you can do this but note that only Kotlin code can use suspension etc.

Comment: @dan1st I updated my post. Success work with suspend function.

Comment: The only download side would be people being confused by kotlin.  But, IMO, the learning curve for kotlin is so low, and the upside of coroutines is so high I think it is  a great solution.

Comment: @eimmer No problem to learn Kotlin when you know Java :-)

Comment: If all you need is "lightweight threads" , why not use Executor and save yourself the complexity?

Comment: @Tenfour04 Because coroutines are lightweight threads. And I create it as many as I want , without OutofMemoryException

Comment: All you're doing here is calling Kotlin functions that run coroutines in the Kotlin world. I'm not sure what that proves. If you need to define your functionality in Java, you are no closer to a solution here. The Executor API is much easier to use in Java than Kotlin coroutines in Java. And it also has the equivalent of "lightweight threads" which are really just Runnables being submitted to thread pools. Very similar to what Kotlin coroutines do under the hood.

Comment: As pointed out by others, you can invoke coroutines from Java, no problem. What you can't do is to suspend inside the Java code. So if you have any operation that is suspendable, then you can make it runnable from Java, but you can't implement it in Java.